# "No pyvenv.cfg file" error thrown when launching Python virtual environment

Tags: virtual-environment, pyvenv

I am working with a Python virtual environment on a Windows machine. I used **venv** with Python 3.10 to create the environment and pip to install libraries. I have used this environment successfully with Jupyter Lab - launching it from the command line.

*(as an aside, I then installed a separate Python 3.7 virtual environment that I used with PyCharm. The following error began after that action).*

I now get the following error when I launch Jupyter Lab:

```
(extractpdf) C:\venv\extractpdf>jupyter lab
No pyvenv.cfg file
```

The above directory (`C:\venv\extractpdf`) does in fact contain a **pyvenv.cfg** file with the following content, which looks as expected according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66921969/6048165):

```
home = C:\Python310
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.10.1
```

I deleted the virtual environment, reinstalled Python 3.10.1, and recreated the virtual environment, while this error persists.

---

This error is occurring with my virtual environments, even when a **pyvenv.cfg** file exists.
The following system interpreters do not have a **pyvenv.cfg** file.

My Python 3.7 system interpreter gives this error:

```
C:\Python37>python
No pyvenv.cfg file
```

while my Python 3.10 system interpreter does not produce an error.

```
C:\Python310>python
Python 3.10.1 (tags/v3.10.1:2cd268a, Dec  6 2021, 19:10:37) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```